# Building a mobille phone app with webview

Tags: mobile, webview

I am willing to write a very simple mobile phone app (Android and iPhone). It is so generic that it should already exists. Only 2 pages : one for choosing the URL of the server and one with only webview. It already works in a browser. I looked at tools for this purpose (Android studio and Ionics) but they are quite difficult to start with. Any hint to get this done quickly ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a simple ionic app and the in-app-browser plugin:

https://ionicframework.com/docs/angular/your-first-app

https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/in-app-browser